# What all is there to know about ping while troubleshooting an internet connection?

Tags: ping

What all is there to know about ping and the IP address to ping while troubleshooting/diagnosing a problem in the internet connection?

For example: I run the command `ping 192.168.1.1 -t` in the command prompt, and if there is no reply I get something is odd, but I don't understand what is and where it is.

I am looking for a complete list (okay, as many as you got), of IP address to ping while troubleshooting my network connection, and an insight into what the status message returned by them implies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always try to ping `default gateway`, you can discover it by this command `ipconfig | findstr Gateway`.

Second you should `ping` something behind your router (gateway), `ping 8.8.8.8`.

Then you should try to `ping google.com` or another site, if site is unreachable you should test your dns with `nslookup google.com` command.

If you're on Linux/Mac, the corresponding commands are `ifconfig | grep "gateway"` instead of `ipconfig` and `dig google.com` instead of `nslookup`

Answer (score 1):

Pinging is a command which tells you if the connection between your computer and a particular domain is working correctly. If the results show a series of replies, the connection is working. The time shows you how fast the connection is. If you see a "timed out" error instead of a reply, there is a breakdown somewhere between your computer and the domain. In this case the next step is to perform a traceroute.

Traceroute is a command which can show you the path a packet of information takes from your computer to one you specify. It will list all the routers it passes through until it reaches its destination, or fails to and is discarded. In addition to this, it will tell you how long each 'hop' from router to router takes.

In Windows, select Start > Programs > Accessories > Command Prompt. This will give you a window like the one below.

Enter the word tracert, followed by a space, then the domain name.

[Information from here](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/troubleshooter/ping.html)